# Auto-populate forms in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

In express it is possible to name inputs like

```
<input name="obj[field1]">
<input name="obj[field2]">
```

to get req.body.obj as a formatted object.

Is the opposite possible? (ie: give an object in input and get the correspective fields populated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible.
The closest solution is to pass data to views with `res.locals` or `app.locals`.

**app.js**

```
app.locals({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' });
```

**index.jade**

```
input(value=locals.foo)
input(value=locals.bar)
```

If you don't know the values of the object up front you can loop the keys and values of an object. I am only familiar with Jade views but your template engine's documentation should explain how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to automatically make Express turn parsed form element names into an object.

It should be quite simple to do manually though:

```
function makeFormObj(req, res, next){
  var obj = {};
  each prop in req.body{
    if(req.body.hasOwnProperty(prop){
      obj[prop] = req.body[prop];
    }
  }
  req.body.obj = obj;
};

app.post('/form'
, makeFormObj
, function(req, res){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2);
  res.send(200, 'parsed body into object');
});
```